# Preventing Toasts from queueing up

Tags: android, toast

When my app starts up, but has not yet loaded a file, the user gets a `Toast` when he clicks the button. It takes about half a second to load, so since he is able to click the button multiple times, it is possible for multiple `Toast`s to get displayed *after* one another.

I tried setting up a `Toast` object as an attribute of my `MainActivity`'s class, but it crashes with `NullPointerException`s.
The implementation:

```
Toast lToast;
(...)
public void exampleMethod() {
    if(lToast == null) {
        lToast.makeText(this, "Noch kein Sound geladen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        lToast.show();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to prevent `Toast`s from queueing up without the need to have a local attribute? And if not, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to prevent them from stacking up, but you could look into disabling the button until the file is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Toast.makeText(...)` is static member of `Toast` class returning `Toast` instance. You've declared `Toast lToast` object but you didnt initialize it.

Change:

`lToast.makeText(this, "Noch kein Sound geladen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`

to

`lToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Noch kein Sound geladen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`

I'm not sure if this will work, but it will prevent raising `NullPointerException`.

Comment: It defenitely got rid of the `NullPointerException` and multiple `Toast`s showing after one another. So thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by "without a local attribute", but digging in to the android code you will find that the long and short delays are as follows

```
private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
```

so when you launch your toast, if you capture the timestamp like so

```
long lastToastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

you should be able to prevent multiple toast messages

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastToastTimestamp > 2000)
{
   lastToastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
   Toast.makeText(this, "Noch kein Sound geladen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

or what about this

make the field:

```
Toast mToast = null;
```

and then the code:

```
if (mToast == null)
{
    mToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Noch kein Sound geladen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    mToast.show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mToast = null;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

If you wanted to make it even more complex you could create your own queue, and only insert new toasts that will be displayed at the expiration of the previous one, if the text given the toast is different from the current one and all the ones in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

**WIIIJBD** has given [a wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640247/2911458).

However in your case instead of blocking the `Toast` you can disable the `Button`.

You can disable the button in `onClick()` and then again set your `onClickListener()` somewhere when you get your callback after you are done loading whatever you intend to load.

Comment: +1 I also like this answer, I have employed this technique where you hide/disable the button until it has completed its operation, maybe replace it with a loading icon/spinner.

Comment: @WIllJBD Very true mate. :)

Comment: I will look into some sort of loading screen later on. Either that or I will try to improve the loading so that it can run smoothely in the background - I only need a few sound files initially, so the rest can be loaded later on. But thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I know that your question wasn't that but anyway... A library I use and recommend using is [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton), which is a Activity strong-dependent library just like Toast, with a lot of customization !

Hope it helps !